# ffmpeg: av1 getting worse results than hevc (h265)

Tags: ffmpeg

I converted an **avc (h264)** file to an **hevc (h265)** file and an **av1** file.

Relative to the **hevc (h265)** file, the **av1** file is far larger in size, and the **av1** file has worse psnr and ssim results too.

With the **hevc (h265)** file, i used the default crf setting (28)

**av1** doesn't have a default crf amount, but i used the ffmpeg recommendation of 30

Here's the command i used to do the **hevc (h265)** conversion

```
C:\Users\l\Desktop\6-app\ffmpeg -i y.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset 8 -vf scale=1920:1080 -r 60 -ab 192k -ar 48k -map_chapters -1 -map_metadata -1 z.mp4
```

Here's the command i used to do the **av1** conversion

```
C:\Users\l\Desktop\6-app\ffmpeg -i y.mp4 -c:v libaom-av1 -crf 30 -b:v 0 -strict experimental -vf scale=1920:1080 -r 60 -ab 192k -ar 48k -map_chapters -1 -map_metadata -1 z.mkv
```

Here are the psnr and ssim results of the **hevc (h265)** file

**ssim**

```
Y:0.981764 (17.390662)
U:0.992258 (21.111573)
V:0.992246 (21.104816)
All:0.985260 (18.315015)
```

**psnr**

```
y:41.620801
u:48.257839
v:47.699066
average:42.905441
min:38.873493
max:58.862531
```

Here are the psnr and ssim results of the **av1** file

**ssim**

```
Y:0.923286 (11.151250)
U:0.991684 (20.800862)
V:0.987425 (19.004970)
All:0.945376 (12.626126)
```

**psnr**

```
y:27.332443
u:44.955360
v:41.569108
average:29.034062
min:8.783696
max:59.518112
```

Here are the size results of the files

**avc**

```
3.9 mb
```

**hevc (h265)**

```
4.6 mb
```

**av1**

```
9.59 mb
```

I know i'm compressing an already well-compressed file, I didn't necessarily expect a smaller file size - but i did expect av1 to outperform hevc (h265))

Here are the actual files

[combo-3-avc-original.mp4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xy7tsys5cswngb/combo-3-avc-original.mp4)

[combo-3-hevc.mp4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnakxv248sz8w9w/combo-3-hevc.mp4)

[combo-3-av1.mkv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/07x5ddc54jn7xzb/combo-3-av1.mkv)

Why would such poor results occur?

**edit:**

· here are the versions of the tools

```
ffmpeg version N-93389-gd15117c996
[libaom-av1 @ 0000025b4839bf40] 1.0.0-1458-ge40c226a6
libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
libavcodec     58. 47.103 / 58. 47.103
libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
```

Comment: libaom is still an experimental encoder - performance will remain in flux for the time being. Which build are you using?

Comment: @gyan · i edited my post with version details at the bottom

Comment: libaom version?

Comment: @gyan ? how do i check libaom version

Comment: When you encode using libaom, ffmpeg log will have a line like this, `[libaom-av1 @ 0000000003990500] 1.0.0-1475-g7c64a0dca`

Comment: @gyan [libaom-av1 @ 0000025b4839bf40] 1.0.0-1458-ge40c226a6

Comment: @gyan · it looks like my version is old ? how do i update it

Comment: Not that old. It's from Mar 13 2019. Try asking at Doom 9.

Comment: @gyan · i registered on their forum · it said that i'd need to activate my account via email · i def put in my correct email · yet, i received no activation email · i checked my junk folder too · also, there's no button to re-send the activation link · and so, i'm unable to use the doom 9 forums

Comment: @gyan · i sent an email to error@doom9.net regarding the registration not working · i never received a response though

Comment: Register from another email address.

Comment: Latest version of ffmpeg in May 2021 and I confirm significantly worse compression efficiency of AV1 compared to H265, despite the far slower encoding time.